# TEST.AI use in node.js mocha test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I want insert  test.ai abilities to my mocha test I try use test-ai-classifier-client
according to https://github.com/testdotai/classifier-client-node, I tried this code  in folder test/rpc-e2e-specs.js
but always get :

> TypeError: ClassifierClient is not a constructor

I dont  understand the using maybe some one help me how to use TEST.AI in this way or another way

Thank,

Comment: Please make an [edit] to include your code so we can better help you

Comment: i just try  the code in the git hub link   https://github.com/testdotai/classifier-client-node,  in  test/rpc-e2e-specs.js folder